# Given a templateURL and a URL how can I get the fields in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const templateURL = '/something/:key1/somethingelse/:key2';
const url = '/something/12/somethingelse/3';
```

How can I get an object like this given inputs above?

```
{
  key1: 12,
  key2: 3
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that both strings, has the same number of parts, you can split both, and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the url. For each part of the url, check the corresponding part of the template. If it starts with `:`, remove the `:` part [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) from the key, and it and the value to the object.

```js
const templateURL = '/something/:key1/somethingelse/:key2'
  .split('/');
  
const url = '/something/12/somethingelse/3';

const result = url.split('/')
  .reduce((r, s, i) => {
    const part = templateURL[i];
    
    if(part.startsWith(':')) {
      r[part.substring(1)] = isNaN(+s) ? s : +s;
    }
    
    return r;
  }, {});
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce` with `split` method.

```js
const templateURL = '/something/:key1/somethingelse/:key2';
const url = '/something/12/somethingelse/3';

function f(temp, url) {
  temp = temp.split('/'), url = url.split('/');
  return temp.reduce((r, e, i) => {
    let [a, b] = e.split(':');
    if (b) r[b] = +url[i];
    return r;
  }, {})
}

console.log(f(templateURL, url))
```